# Format datePicker Header - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker

How can I format my datepicker to have black text in the header and black button text? Here is my code:

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
DateFormat formatter =
    DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'); //specifies day/month/year format

final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(


    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          //primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: kPrimaryColor),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
        ),),
        child: child,
      );
    },
    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
```

And this is what the datepicker currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the button text color you can use a `colorScheme` for the `buttonTheme`.

For setting the header text color you can use `onPrimary`.

```
builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                return Theme(
                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                        primary: kPrimaryColor,
                        onPrimary: Colors.black,),
                    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                      colorScheme: Theme.of(context)
                          .colorScheme
                          .copyWith(primary: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: child,
                );
              }),
```

Result:

[image: res]